# Scala - console based development workflow

Tags: scala

Over the last 10 days, I've been reading "Programming in Scala" and writing some Scala code.

As you can see in my [GitHub Scala playground](https://github.com/ttsiodras/ScalaPlayground/tree/master/3.usingPackagesForBenchmarking), I am starting to really like this language - it is as fast as OCaml (thanks to JVM's HotSpot technology), protects me from my typos (and bugs!) with its strong and static type system, and best of all:  enterprise-wise, it doesn't live in a remote "island" (like Haskell and OCaml) ... because it has the huge ecosystem of the JVM.

My only problem so far:

Even though I've figured out how to develop my Scala code under VIM with sbt-quickfix, or under Emacs with Ensime (and thus have autocompletion and error navigation), I have so far failed to find a way to debug my code, with the same ease that I do for Python:

```
bash$ python -m pdb ./someCode.py
```

All the entries Google points to, are basically saying: "use this IDE that I really like..."

There are reasons however - no point in enumerating them, you either know them or you don't - that people like me prefer (a) [programmable editors](https://www.thanassis.space/myvim.html) and (b) a standalone debugger, available outside their editor.

If you are one of the few like-minded people that dislike IDEs and happen to use Scala, I'd be really interested to know how you debug - in fact I'd be interested to hear your entire workflow.

Mine, so far is:

- Add the `sbt-quickfix` to my SBT's project/ folder (just [look at my code](https://github.com/ttsiodras/ScalaPlayground/tree/master/3.usingPackagesForBenchmarking) in this GitHub repos)
- Spawn `sbt` in a terminal, and run `~compile` so that it automatically builds when I change something in my sources
- VIM automatically receives errors and shows them.
- When compilation is green, hit ENTER in the `sbt` terminal, type `run`
- etc

Ensime is even better, allowing auto-completion as well:

- `sbt gen-ensime`
- Spawn emacs editing one of my .scala files, and `M-x ensime`
- Use `ensime-typecheck-all` (mapped to F7 in my dotfiles) and when all is OK...
- `ensime-sbt-do-run`

Here's to hoping I am not alone - and that someone out there will help me with standalone debugging, too... the last challenge before I fully embrace Scala :-)

Comment: What exactly you want from debugger? I'm using emacs + ensime, it has an integrated debugger (C-c C-d prefix by default). If not ensime i'm running `sat-start` with `~testQuick` or `~compile`

Comment: @4lex1v: I want the really basic things provided by almost all cmd-line debuggers (`gdb`, `python -m pdb`, `perl -d`, etc) e.g. the ability to 'l'ist around the currently executing line, set a 'b'reakpoint on a file's line, 'd'isplay the values of variables, 'n'ext line execution, etc. I googled for `sat-start` but found no Scala related links - any pointers?

Comment: That was `sbt-start`, autocorrection, sorry. I've never used cmd-line debugger before, sorry, but what you describe perfectly doable with ensime. At least i've never heard about any cmd-line debugger for scala

Comment: My understanding was that scala inserts the same source and line attributes that Java does? In which case it should be possible (though not always friendly, given how scala translates to bytecode) to use `jdb` just as with java?

Comment: @4lex1v: I just tested debugging under ensime, and it is indeed just fine for my needs - thank you, I somehow missed that ensime wasn't about just autocompletion. Only one complaint - the "currently executing line" and "breakpoint set" indications are not visible in text mode (i.e. `emacs -nw`)... will try to raise a point about it upstream.

Comment: @ttsiodras Sorry, i'm using emacs in a UI, not in terminal, it shows breakpoint on a fringe. Btw yesterday someone started a topic on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/2osqn3/is_emacs_still_a_good_editor_for_scala/)

Comment: @4lex1v: I am not the one that started it, but the discussion on Reddit is indeed interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out `ensime` has a debugging mode, which I somehow missed. Paired with Emacs/evil, I've spent the last couple of days inside Emacs and Scala - and it all works perfectly... autocompletion, spawning sbt in a buffer when I want to run, *and* debugging.

My only remaining problem is about working with Ensime from inside `screen`-ed sessions, which is my usual modus operandi (over SSH connections). The markers of Ensime debugger's *current line* and *breakpoint set* are placed on the left fringe - which works fine in graphics mode Emacs, but isn't visible in text-mode Emacs. I've [opened a ticket](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-server/issues/702) and the guys there apparently have a plan for a solution.